# lm with an interaction term using the pipe %>% operator

Tags: r, lm

I have a tibble with three columns, `y`, `x1`, and `x2`. I can do a regular regression `lm(y ~ x1 + x2)` using `%>%` by simply doing

```
dat %>%
 select(y, x1, x2) %>%
 lm()
```

However if I want to do `lm(y ~ x1*x2)`, how do I go about doing it? The only way that comes to my mind is

```
dat %>%
 mutate(x1x2 = x1 * x2) %>%
 select(y, x1, x2, x1x2) %>%
 lm()
```

but I don't like this solution and would like something simpler.

Comment: `dat %>% lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1*x2, data = .)` (you don't need the `select` if you use a formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the formula you want to `lm()`

```
dat %>%
  select(y, x1, x2) %>%
  lm(formula = (y ~x1*x2))
```